# merge results in two variables into one variable sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two variables say

```
DECLARE @ONE NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TWO NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

and I have set values into these two variables

```
SET @ONE= 'select a from Table1 AS Result1'
SET @TWO = 'select b from Table2  AS Result2'

Result1     | Result2
  1         |  2
  3         |  4
```

Now I want to merge results into one variable

```
DECLARE @RESULTS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @RESULTS = result from @one + result from @two
```

My desired output will be

```
---------------------
| Result1    Result2 |
|  1           2     |
|                    |
|   3          4     |
 ---------------------
```

This is what I have tried

```
SET @RESULTS = '
    select * 
    FROM (
        select * 
        from '+ @ONE+'
    ) RESULT1 JOIN (
        select * 
        from '+@TWO+'
    ) RESULT2 ON 1=1'
```

Comment: Something like select concat (a,b) from result1 join result2 on some_condtion?

Comment: there is no condition

Comment: Will these two result sets have the same number or rows? Is there any ordering or joining key.

Comment: Will have same number of rows and there is no joining conditions

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

**Test Data:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'Table1')>0
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Table1
END

IF OBJECT_ID(N'Table2')>0
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Table2
END

CREATE TABLE Table1 (Col1 VARCHAR(100))
CREATE TABLE Table2 (Col2 VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO Table1
VALUES('1'),('3')

INSERT INTO Table2
VALUES('2'),('4')
```

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @ONE NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @OneColumns NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TWO NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TWOColumns NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @Table1Result TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),Column1 VARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @Table2Result TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),Column2 VARCHAR(100))

SET @ONE = 'SELECT Col1 FROM Table1'
SET @TWO = 'SELECT Col2 FROM Table2'

SET @OneColumns = REPLACE(REPLACE(@ONE,'FROM','!'),'SELECT','')
SET @OneColumns = SUBSTRING(@OneColumns,1,CHARINDEX('!',@OneColumns)-1)
SET @OneColumns = LTRIM(RTRIM(@OneColumns))
SET @OneColumns = Replace(@OneColumns,',',', a.')
SET @OneColumns = 'a.'+@OneColumns

SET @TwoColumns = REPLACE(REPLACE(@TWO,'FROM','!'),'SELECT','')
SET @TwoColumns = SUBSTRING(@TwoColumns,1,CHARINDEX('!',@TwoColumns)-1)
SET @TwoColumns = LTRIM(RTRIM(@TwoColumns))
SET @TwoColumns = Replace(@TwoColumns,',',', b.')
SET @TwoColumns = 'b.'+@TwoColumns

SET @ONE = REPLACE(@ONE,'SELECT ', 'SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS TId, ')
SET @TWO = REPLACE(@TWO,'SELECT ', 'SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS TId, ')

Print @ONE
Print @Two
Print @OneColumns
Print @TwoColumns

SET @SQL = 'SELECT '+@OneColumns+','+@TwoColumns+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
+'FROM('+@ONE++')AS a'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
+'INNER JOIN('+@Two+')AS b'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
+'ON a.TId = b.TId'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)

EXEC (@SQL)
```

**Cleanup:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'Table1')>0
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Table1
END

IF OBJECT_ID(N'Table2')>0
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Table2
END
```

Comment: I can't use Table Variable as my columns are creating dynamically :( Which means columns in the @One can be varied

Comment: So the SQL from [@One] and [@two] can have any number of columns but will both tables have the same number of columns?

Comment: I have modified the query as requested, please validate

Comment: I have also modified the script to remove the Id's from the final result set.

Comment: @Sourav, Please can you up vote and accept the answer if the solution was useful

Answer (score 0):

You can add RowID to your `SELECT` and then `INNER JOIN` them:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1  (a INT)
CREATE TABLE #Table2  (b INT)

INSERT INTO #Table1 SELECT 1
INSERT INTO #Table1 SELECT 3

INSERT INTO #Table2 SELECT 2
INSERT INTO #Table2 SELECT 4

DECLARE @ONE NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TWO NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @ONE= 'select a, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a) AS ROWID from #Table1 '
SET @TWO = 'select b, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b) AS ROWID from #Table2  '


DECLARE @RESULTS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
    select a, b 
    FROM (
        '+ @ONE+' 
    ) RESULT1 
    INNER JOIN (
        '+@TWO+'
    ) RESULT2 ON 
    RESULT1.ROWID=RESULT2.ROWID'


EXEC sp_executesql @RESULTS
```